# How to disable just the max-line-length tslint in VS

Tags: visual-studio, tslint

Is it possible to just disable just the max-line-length warning you get from the tsLint but not using: // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length. Is there a way this can be turned off permanently. Not the linter just that feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `tslint.json` file, you can change the `max-line-length` property to the following:

```
max-line-length: [false]
```

Comment: Thanks so much man! That little red line was driving me insane

Comment: @Jared No problem :D 
If it worked, please consider marking as answer :) 
Enjoy!

Comment: how to do this just for one file ?

Comment: @ATHER at the top of the file put `// tslint:disable:max-line-length` and if you want to enable it again at a certain line do `// tslint:enable:max-line-length`